# switching between wordpress text/visual editor makes anchor tags disappear

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to create anchor points in my page for users to jump to.  When I create the anchor points in the text editor in wordpress, if I ever switch to visual editor, the anchor tags disappear.  Here is the code I am using in the text editor:

```
<div>
   <a id="posts" class="anchor">&nbsp;</a>
   <h4>Key Blog Posts</h4>
   Andrea Radke-Moss, <a href="http://www.juvenileinstructor.org/mormon-studies-in-the-classroom-mormon-women-patriarchy-and-equality/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">"Mormon Studies in the Classroom: Mormon Women, Patriarchy and Equality,"</a> Juvenile Instructor.
</div>
```

When I switch the the visual editor (regardless if I saved it or not while in text editor), the anchor tag disappears and I am left with this:

```
<div>
   &nbsp;
   <h4>Key Blog Posts</h4>
   Andrea Radke-Moss, <a href="http://www.juvenileinstructor.org/mormon-studies-in-the-classroom-mormon-women-patriarchy-and-equality/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">"Mormon Studies in the Classroom: Mormon Women, Patriarchy and Equality,"</a> Juvenile Instructor.
```

After doing some research, this seems like a common problem with Wordpress when there is no text between the anchor tags (which is why I tried the `&nbsp;`).  Has anyone been able to conquer this problem?

Update: I tried putting a period in between the tags with `style="font-size: 0px";`.  Saved, switched to visual editor, and the period was now outside my anchor tags!  Grrrr....

Comment: You are not using `href` attribute, which may be the source of this problem. Try like this: `<a id="posts" class="anchor" href="#">&nbsp;</a>`

Comment: Really trying to avoid using `href`. I don't want a clickable space there, even though it wouldn't do anything. It tends to make the page jump around, even if it's just a little bit.

Comment: You can prevent click behavior of a element using javascript

Comment: `href=#` jumps to the top of my page, `href=""` and `href=javascript:void(0)` are both taken out by the visual editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got something to work. Here's the code I used:

```
<a id="posts" class="anchor" href="#posts">&nbsp;</a>
```

I couldn't get rid of the `&nbsp;`, so it still has a clickable spot, but at least when it's clicked on, it doesn't jump around like `href="#"` does.